# R Script: Determine whether the script is run in the GUI or from command line

Tags: user-interface, command-line, r, scripting

Is it possible to determine - from within the script - whether the script is running in the R-GUI (specifically R.app on OS X) or whether it has been called from Terminal/command line (i.e. `R --vanilla -f script.R`)? If so, how is this possible?

I'm asking because I have a script that can run parallelized (using the `doMC` library), which should not be used from the GUI. Sometimes I need to further process the data calculated in the script, so I'd like to call the script from the GUI on these occasions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for `interactive()`?

Answer (score 2):

In `C`, you would use the [`isatty`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/isatty/) function.  If you could find an equivalent function in `R` (probably in a UNIX or file system library), that should help.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I can't find an R-equivalent to `isatty`, also there's nothing in the help pages matching *tty*, but this way surely would be neat.