# Determine whether MATLAB was launched from OS GUI or as a Parallel Toolbox thread

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

In a similar style to [this question about R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020790/r-script-determine-whether-the-script-is-run-in-the-gui-or-from-command-line), is there a way to determine whether a given MATLAB instance was launched by the user or whether it was spawned by the parallel toolbox scheduler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Warning: untested code*

This seems like it might do the trick:

```
if isempty(getCurrentWorker)
% Do things if launched as a worker
else
% Do things if launched in a GUI session
end
```

Here's the reference: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/getcurrentworker.html

Comment: I think you'd be better off using getCurrentTask rather than getCurrentWorker. getCurrentWorker only works on the job manager, not the other schedulers.