# R Is Run in GUI or Not?

Tags: r, user-interface, command

I note the following, click [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020790/r-script-determine-whether-the-script-is-run-in-the-gui-or-from-command-line):

I ask the same question, in the sense that I need to know whether my R environment has been run from terminal, or in a GUI type environment.

The motivation for my question, is I produce a number of `.pdf` reports, and, if the user has called the functions that produce the reports under GUI, then I want to open the reports using the system default `.pdf` program, but if the script has been run from the command line, or via a session commenced at the commandline, then this should be suppressed.

In RStudio, if I run `interactive()`, the result is `TRUE`, and if I open an R session at the terminal and run the same command, the result is also `TRUE`, so, my question is essentially, how can I differentiate? I am running MacOSX, but would like the answer to be relevant to mac, unix and windoze.

Cheers,

Comment: When you say "open an R session at the terminal" are you opening the terminal and executing `R` or `R CMD BATCH`?

Comment: `echo 'interactive()' | R` says `FALSE`, so it's working correctly. The question is do you really want to determine whether a GUI is running or do you want to determine whether R is running interactively (in which case `interactive()` would suffice)?

Comment: I am executing `R`, NOT `R CMD BATCH`, so, sessions opened via `R` or, sessions run via executable R script `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript` should return `FALSE`, if the session is run in something like RStudio, it should return `TRUE`

Answer (score 2):

`commandArgs()` will output the command line that launched the R session and `.Platform$OS.type` will report the OS so:

```
switch(.Platform$OS.type,
  windows = if (grepl("Rterm", commandArgs())) cat("terminal\n") else cat("GUI\n"),
  ...fill in for each other operating system...
)
```